# GridSplitter MinWidth with fixed size

Tags: wpf, silverlight, xaml, silverlight-toolkit, gridsplitter

I have a Grid with 2 columns separated by a GridSplitter using the following XAML code :

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="100" MinWidth="20" />
    <ColumnDefinition Width="10" />
    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" MinWidth="100" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <Rectangle Fill="Blue" />
    <GridSplitter Grid.Column="1" Background="LightGray" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" />
    <Rectangle Fill="Yellow" Grid.Column="2" />
</Grid>
```

**Problem** : The MinWidth of the Column on the right is ignored

- I definitely need the first column Width to be "100px" when page loads, so It cannot be * sized.
- I do not want to set a MaxWidth on the first column

*I know that has been adressed before but it always suggest to set column size to * or set a maxWidth on the first column... I don't want that.

---

Found a solution, **but its UGLY! :p**, anybody has a cleaner way to achieve what I want... CODELESS (if possible)?

```
private void Grid_SizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
{
   var g = (Grid)sender;

   Double maxW = e.NewSize.Width - g.ColumnDefinitions[2].MinWidth - g.ColumnDefinitions[1].ActualWidth;
   g.ColumnDefinitions[0].MaxWidth = maxW;
}
```

Comment: Did you try to set the column Width to Auto instead of * ?

Comment: No it does not fix the problem setting the Width of First Col to Auto.  Also I want my 1st Column to be 100px when opening (I cannot set its content width to 100 either cause it won't resize after)

Comment: What you want is: first column need to be 100 px at startup, and cannot be less than 20, and last column takes all the space left on the window on startup, but need to be at least 100 px?

Comment: exactly, after startup (with left col set at 100px) I want the GridSplitter to behave normally, with left col Min to 20px and Right Col min to 100px.

Comment: why do you not want a max width on the first column?

Comment: I don't want to set a max width on the first column because I don't know the size of the Grid in advance.  I can calculate and set the MaxWidth of first column in code at the GridSizeChanged, but its not clean at all.  I'd like a better solution

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The basic problem is that a grid splitter works by adjusting the width of the left column *only* and assumes the right column will *star-size* to fit the remaining space.

That means the problem you are trying to solve is actually "how do I limit the max width of the left column so that the right column does not get too small?". This is basically what your code sample is doing.

If you want a more portable solution, that you can implement in XAML, create a Silverlight [behavior](http://www.silverlightshow.net/items/Behaviors-and-Triggers-in-Silverlight-3.aspx) that can be applied to a grid (as shown below). It will attach to the parent grid's `SizeChanged` event and do pretty much exactly what your code snippet does, but being a behavior you can drag and drop them in Blend or attach them in XAML.

Here is a sample behavior I threw together for you as an example (based on your own code):

### MinWidthSplitterBehavior.cs

```
using System;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Interactivity;

namespace GridSplitterMinWidth
{
    public class MinWidthSplitterBehavior : Behavior<Grid>
    {
        public Grid ParentGrid { get; set; }

        protected override void OnAttached()
        {
            base.OnAttached();
            ParentGrid = this.AssociatedObject as Grid;
            ParentGrid.SizeChanged += parent_SizeChanged;
        }

        void parent_SizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (ParentGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Count == 3)
            {
                Double maxW = e.NewSize.Width - ParentGrid.ColumnDefinitions[2].MinWidth -
                              ParentGrid.ColumnDefinitions[1].ActualWidth;
                ParentGrid.ColumnDefinitions[0].MaxWidth = maxW;
            }
        }

        protected override void OnDetaching()
        {
            base.OnDetaching();
            if (ParentGrid != null)
            {
                ParentGrid.SizeChanged -= parent_SizeChanged;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

### and use it like this:

```
<UserControl x:Class="GridSplitterMinWidthApp.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:GridSplitterMinWidth="clr-namespace:GridSplitterMinWidth"
    xmlns:interactivity="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity"
    xmlns:Controls="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls;assembly=System.Windows.Controls"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="400">

    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="100" MinWidth="20" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="10" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" MinWidth="100" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
                <GridSplitterMinWidth:MinWidthSplitterBehavior/>
            </interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
            <Rectangle Fill="Blue" />
            <Controls:GridSplitter Grid.Column="1" Background="LightGray" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
            </Controls:GridSplitter>
            <Rectangle Fill="Yellow" Grid.Column="2" />
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Comment: I don't think this is generally true, given if you star-size everything the MinWidth of the right column is respected.  See my answer for more details.

Comment: @PatrickV: Given it's now 2014 and I have not used Silverlight for years you may well be right :)

Answer (score 4):

This seems to me to be a bug in the WPF GridSplitter.  The root of the problem is using different types of values for the Width column.

This will not work:

```
<Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="100" MinWidth="20" />
    <ColumnDefinition Width="10" />
    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" MinWidth="100" />
</Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
```

Because column [0] has a width of "100", an explicit number type, and column [1] has a width of "*".  But this will work:

```
<Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" MinWidth="20" />
    <ColumnDefinition Width="10" />
    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" MinWidth="100" />
</Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
```

When you do this, both the left and right "MinWidth" values are respected by the GridSplitter.  To me, this means bug in WPF.

In my case, I need to set the left column to "Auto" with a minimum, and the right to "*" with a minimum, but there doesn't seem to be any way to do that without some form of codebehind.  My guess is that the simplest solution will be to just * size everything and use a custom behavior to replace the "auto" functionality of the column (since that is a one-column, one-time fix), but I have yet to do that.  Hopefully, the XAML will look something like this:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" MinWidth="20" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="10" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" MinWidth="100" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
        <MyBehaviors:GridColumnStarSizedToAutoBehavior Column="0"/>
    </interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
    ...
</Grid>
```

Update*:  I implemented a behavior as noted in this post above.  it was not as simple as I was hoping due to Grid limitations.  I can not post the solution due to company limitations, but I can give some tips.  The biggest problem I ran into is that you can't really get away from star sizing, even with behavior codebehind, because it makes the MinWidth stop working for the star-sized columns.

To compensate for this involved processing all the columns for the grid.  You have to take the columns you want auto-sized, determine their children's desired size by getting UIElements by column and using Measure on them, and then changing their star-size-value to a percentage of total available star-size spacing.  You also have to adjust non-auto-star-sized columns star-size value accordingly.

As an example, consider a grid with 3 columns:  1st star-sized with MinWidth we want to be auto, 2nd auto-sized without MinWidth, and third star-sized with MinWidth.  If the control is 100 units wide, and the content of the first column wants 25 pixels, and the content of the third column wants 5 pixels, the code has to star-size the first and last column as "25*" and "70*" respectively (or any other numbers that get the right ratio).

This was non-trivial, but did work in the end.  I did not account for column spanning.

Sorry I can't post the code.