# WPF resizable grid: doesn't work when using styles and won't respect minimum height/width

Tags: wpf

I am trying to build a `Grid` in WPF that can be resized by the user by dragging on the `GridSplitter`, and the contents of each `ColumnDefinition` or `GridDefinition` should resize to fit. Since these `Gridsplitter`s require some styling, I created two named styles for them to use whenever necessary. In the fully-reproducable example below, the button should be resized both horizontally and vertically when `GridSplitter`s are dragged:

```
<Window x:Class="MyProject.GUI.TestWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="TestWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    
    <Grid>
        <Grid.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="GridSplitter" x:Key="VerticalSplitter">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Gray"/>
                <Setter Property="Width" Value="3"/>
                <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
                <Setter Property="Margin" Value="2,0,2,0"/>
            </Style>
            <Style TargetType="GridSplitter" x:Key="HorizontalSplitter">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Gray"/>
                <Setter Property="Height" Value="3"/>
                <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
                <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,2,0,2"/>
            </Style>
        </Grid.Resources>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="auto" MinWidth="220"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="auto" MinWidth="100"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Grid Grid.Column="0">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="auto" MinHeight="100"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="auto" MinHeight="100"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <Button Grid.Row="0"/>
            <GridSplitter Grid.Row="1" Style="{StaticResource HorizontalSplitter}"/>
            <Label Grid.Row="2"/>
        </Grid>
        <GridSplitter Grid.Column="1" Style="{StaticResource VerticalSplitter}"/>
        <Grid Grid.Column="2"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Resizing works with the horizontal `GridSplitter`, but not with the vertical one - the `GridSplitter` - it moves, but the button doesn't stretch and is left behind.

However, if I don't apply the style, but write out attributes explicitly for each `GridSplitter`, like this:

```
<GridSplitter Grid.Row="1" Background="Gray" Height="3" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0,2,0,2"/>

<GridSplitter Grid.Column="1" Background="Gray" Width="3" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"/>
```

...then suddenly it starts working, button is resized both horizontally and vertically. I don't understand why this happens, can anyone explain how should I set this up to be able to use a style to avoid having to repeat these markups when I need more `GridSplitter`s?

The second issue is that while `MinWidth` and `MinHeight` of first columns and rows is respected, these values of the last column and row are not - meaning the `GridSplitter`s can be dragged down and right outside of the window bounds. I am not sure why this is happening either.

Can anyone help?

EDIT: I temporarily worked around the second issue by using [MinWidthSplitterBehavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11265698/gridsplitter-minwidth-with-fixed-size), (by also writing a similar MinHeightSplitterBehavior) but it's an ugly one since it requires to specify the usage of that behavior everywhere where `GridSplitter` is used, rather than making it default behavior. Still looking for a better option. But solving the first issue is more important.

Comment: The Style named "VerticalSplitter" lacks `HorizontalAlignment` while you directly set that property of the second GridSplitter below. See the sample at [How to: Resize Columns with a GridSplitter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/controls/how-to-resize-columns-with-a-gridsplitter)

Comment: @emoacht Thank you, that was it. I can't believe I missed that. Any suggestions for solving the second issue?